# batch parsing multiple registry dumps to csv

Tags: batch-file, python-3.x, text-parsing

I need to create a csv using a registry dump with the key as the heading and the value as the data from a txt file.

There will be more than 5000 files to dump into a spreadsheet for reporting purposes.

I cannot access the machines in question, i only have the txt files with the output so i can only deal with the data in the files and how it is. it would be easier if i had access as i could create the ouput how i want using REG query but this is not an option.

I can't install 3rd party tools or software. i have what windows 7 comes with only.
**edit: i can use python 3.4 if needed but i have very limited knowledge of it.**

What would be the quickest and best method of doing this with batch?
I've some batch knowledge but can't seem to get to grips with this.
i've only been able to find solutions using reg query of a single registry.

Some values can be blank or contain a single character which also makes it tricky.
Here is an example of what is in a txt files. The headers and the value are what matters and there could be 50 keys out of 200 that are needed.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\INVENTORY\MACHINE]
"WINDOWS"="Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]"
"PROCESSOR"="              Intel(R) Celeron(R) D CPU 3.20GHz"
"SYSPAGEFILE"="1524MB"
"DISPLAY_RES"="800x600"
"CPU_NAME"="Intel(R) PRO/1000 GT Desktop Adapter"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\INVENTORY\MACHINE\SOFTWARE]
"OS.Arch"="x86"
```

Example of csv output

```
MACHINE_ID,WINDOWS,CPU_NAME,CPU_PROCESSOR,SYSPAGEFILE,DISPLAY_RES,MEMORY_TOTAL,MEMORY_AVAILABLE,RAM,SYSTEM_LOCALE,TIME_ZONE,INSTALL_DATE,  
    1a,Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600],Intel[R] PRO/1000 GT Desktop Adapter,x86 Family 15 Model 6 Stepping 5 GenuineIntel ~3192 Mhz,1524MB,800x600, ,3362103296K, ,en-us;English [United States],[GMT] Greenwich Mean Time ,-,5/19/2011, 
    1b,Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600],Intel[R] PRO/1000 GT Desktop Adapter,x86 Family 15 Model 6 Stepping 5 GenuineIntel ~3192 Mhz,1524MB,800x600, ,3580018688K, ,en-us;English [United States],[GMT] Greenwich Mean Time ,-,9/26/2013, 
    1c,Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600],-,x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10 GenuineIntel ~2593 Mhz, , , ,372687298560K, ,en-us;English [United States],[GMT] Greenwich Mean Time ,19/08/2014,
```

**Update:**
Magoo's solution works with txt files in some scenarios including the sample provided but the reg files i have seem to be ucs2 LE or utf16 encoding which is messy and some have strange characters that can cause problems, if he had a full file problem solving would be easier but not an option for me. I've marked his solution as correct for the question i posted.

I did manage to piece together a python 3.4 solution which i'll post below for anyone who can use it if they want. it's a bit crude, doesn't handle duplicate reg keys but i am only a beginner.

```
import csv, re, os
from fnmatch import fnmatch

current = os.getcwd()
datadir = current + '\\data\\'
r = {}
rows=[]

with open('headers.csv','r') as headread:
    head = csv.DictReader(headread,dialect='excel',delimiter=',')
    headers = head.fieldnames

with open('data.csv','w') as f:
    f_csv = csv.DictWriter(f, headers,extrasaction='ignore',lineterminator = '\n')
    f_csv.writeheader()

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(datadir):
    for filename in files:
        parse = (os.path.join(path, filename))
        with open(parse,encoding='utf16') as f:
            for line in f:
                li=line.strip()
                if li.startswith("\""):
                    (heading, val) = line.split("\"=\"")
                    val=val[:-1]
                    r[heading.strip("\"")] = val.strip("\"")
                    rows=[r]
        with open('data.csv','a') as f:
            f_csv = csv.DictWriter(f, headers,extrasaction='ignore',lineterminator = '\n')
            f_csv.writerows(rows)
```

This script expects to have the headers in headers.csv and for the file(s) in question to be in a 'data' folder in the same directory. i'm a beginner so probably not the best way go about it but it helped me.

Comment: Just to prevent erroneous assumptions, can you also show an example of your expected csv output of the above text file snippet?

Comment: @rojo i've updated it with a csv snippet. i've had some trouble using csv with excel and was thinking of using tabs instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
:: delete output file
DEL "newfile.txt" >NUL 2>nul
:: remove variables starting $ or #
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
CALL :zap#
:: Set column headers
SET /a columncount=0
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN (q27905448.ct8) DO (
 SET /a columncount+=1
 SET "$!columncount!=%%a"
 SET "#!columncount!=%%a"
)
CALL :show
FOR %%f IN (q27905448.txt) DO (
 CALL :zap#
 SET "#1=%%~nf"
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN (%%f) DO (
  SET "name=%%~a"
  SET "value=%%~b"
  CALL :fit
 )
 CALL :show
)


GOTO :EOF

:: remove variables starting #
:zap#
FOR  /F "delims==" %%z In ('set # 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%z="
GOTO :eof

:show
SET "outline="
FOR /L %%x IN (1,1,%columncount%) DO (
 IF "!$%%x:~0,1!" neq "[" (
  SET "outline=!outline!,"!#%%x!""
 )
)
>>"newfile.txt" ECHO(%outline:~1%
GOTO :eof

:fit
IF "%name:~0,1%"=="[" GOTO newsection
IF %section% equ 0 GOTO :EOF 
FOR /L %%x IN (%section%,1,%columncount%) DO (
 IF /i "!$%%x!"=="%name%" FOR /f "tokens=*" %%y IN ("%value%") DO SET "#%%x=%%y"&GOTO :EOF 
 IF "!$%%x:~0,1!" equ "[" GOTO :eof
)
GOTO :eof

:: Locate sectionname index or 0 if section not being reported
:newsection
SET /a section=0
FOR /L %%x IN (1,1,%columncount%) DO (
 IF /i "!$%%x!"=="%name%" SET /a section=%%x+1&GOTO :EOF 
)
GOTO :eof
```

I used a file named `q27905448.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces newfile.txt

You don't say where the machinename comes from. I simply used the name of the sourcefile.

Using a file to define the required data fields:

```
Machine_ID
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\INVENTORY\MACHINE]
WINDOWS
PROCESSOR
SYSPAGEFILE
Sausages
DISPLAY_RES
Candlepower
CPU_NAME

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\INVENTORY\MACHINE\SOFTWARE]
STRENGTH
OS.Arch
```

That is, [sectionname] fields-required as a list in `q27905448.ct8` (I added a couple of bogus fields to represent missing values).

The first entry is a special - to get the machine_ID. The method of applying data is in the code - simply set `#1` to the required value.

There would be a list of files assigned to `%%f` - no idea what exactly you want to do, so perhaps this would come from a file or a `dir/b` scan.

From there, it's a matter of assigning the values found to `#n` with the template in `$n`. Given your input file, my result was

```
"Machine_ID","WINDOWS","PROCESSOR","SYSPAGEFILE","Sausages","DISPLAY_RES","Candlepower","CPU_NAME","STRENGTH","OS.Arch"
"q27905448","Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]","Intel(R) Celeron(R) D CPU 3.20GHz","1524MB","","800x600","","Intel(R) PRO/1000 GT Desktop Adapter","","x86"
```

Comment: i'll have a look at this now. the machien ID's come from a reg key in the file somewhere but uses that key name "Machine_ID", i was using: dir /s /b *dhcout* in a for loop to loop through each file in the directory as each file has that dhcout in it's name and a unique identifier to keep them unique.

Comment: i've tried it and it doesn't work i get empty output for the values, headers work fine. i used a header file and 1 file in question but this part does not run :FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN (%%f) DO (
  SET "name=%%~a"
  SET "value=%%~b"
  CALL :fit
 )

Comment: So - did you display the content of `%%f`? Did it contain a valid filename? What was that filename?

Comment: replaced q27905448.ct8 with headers.txt
replaced q27905448.txt with dhcout_9332flgl3tvvQb_.txt
contents of the dhcout file were not parsed. contents are the same as i posted.
i made a new file and put in exactly as i posted into it and tested that too and it didn't output any of the values, just a hyphen

Comment: sorry scratch the hyphen, just my eyes seeing things at this stage! The values are blank still.

Comment: i see what the problem is. i don't have the section name in my header file because it's not important where in the registry it was, just the key itself because there is could be 100 different sections.
i like how it goes by section, could it also ignore sections and just find the keys and values?

Comment: Still doesn't work properly. there's something in the files that causes to give an unexpected 0 error before it even gets to that key.

Comment: Without example data, it's impossible to diagnose. Using your original data as posted and removing the `[sectionname]` entries in `q27905448.ct8` so that you simply have a list of `name`s, all you need do is to change the `SET /a section=0` in `:newsection` to `SET /a section=1` It will make the procedure a little inefficient, but it will work to show the spreadsheet of values. The output I posted was direct from a test run and this change to make it "sectionless" hasn't changed that.

Comment: The problem seems to be encoding. the files are utf-16.